# No global config file found for switch system in OPAM on Windows

Tags: windows, cygwin, ocaml, opam

So I installed OCaml on Windows today from the official installer as well as the required Cygwin packages. I did the correct steps following 
"$ opam init", which worked fine. Then, to test out OPAM, I tried to install the "Core" package, to which I got the following error.

```
$ opam install core
[ERROR] No global config file found for switch system. Switch broken ?
[ERROR] No global config file found for switch system. Switch broken ?
[ERROR] No package named core found.
[ERROR] No global config file found for switch system. Switch broken ?
```

I'm new to OCaml and programming, and am not great at figuring this stuff out yet, so I'm lost. I want to know how to make OPAM find this file so I can install packages.

Answer (score 0):

Have you run the following command after performing `opam init`?

```
eval `opam config env`
```

In addition, for the first time installation, you need to switch to a specific version of compiler. How about trying the following?

```
opam switch 4.02.3
```

or

```
opam switch 4.03.0
```

(and remember running the eval ... command)

Comment: I tried this, I keep getting errors for the switch command saying that "4.02.3" and "4.03.0" are not compiler versions, and for the eval one it keeps saying '\r' isn't a valid command.

Comment: Can you execute the command `opam switch -a` to see the list of available compilers?

Comment: $ opam switch -a
[ERROR] No global config file found for switch system. Switch broken ?
system C system  System compiler (4.02.3)

[WARNING] The environment is not in sync with the current switch.
          You should run: eval `opam config env`

Comment: but I can't run `opam config env` because it keeps saying that `\r` is  not a valid command or something.

Comment: This is because the `\r` is a part Windows's newline. I guess the configuration of Opam for Windows is quite tricky. Can you check this page instead: http://protz.github.io/ocaml-installer/